# Excluding dependency when compiling jar file

Tags: android, ant, jar, intellij-idea, artifacts

I am building a jar file which contains compiled class files. This is to be used in other projects.

Jar file project (project A)
Project using jar as dependency (project B)

My issue is that the project (A) that builds this jar and the project (B) that will use this jar as a dependency both have Holo Everywhere as a dependency which equates to holo everywhere clashes on building the final project (B).

I would like to either exclude these files before the build of the jar (A) or automatically strip them out post build.

I am using Intellij Idea to build the jar via the artifact build tools. I have been exploring manual Ant builds but had no success.

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated, 
Many thanks.

Comment: Change for one of library "Holo Everywhere" dependency form compiled to provided

Comment: It would be much easier if you use maven or gradle